# edittext generating by clicking Add button and removing by pressing delete button accrding to this xml

Tags: java, android, android-intent

this is my xml so now i need to create a EditText by clicking Add Button then new EditText will show up under previews one aslo when i need to revome it to click Delete Button and it will be gone,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:padding="5dip"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >
     <TextView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Group Ping"
         android:padding="5dp"/>

     <EditText 
         android:id="@+id/edAddress"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
         android:hint="www.baidu.com"/>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
       android:orientation="horizontal" >

      <Button
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:id="@+id/btadd"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"/>
     <Button
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:id="@+id/btsub"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete"/>
     <Button
         android:layout_weight="30"
         android:id="@+id/btgping"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Ping"/>
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use visibility of edittext

Answer (score 2):

Initially in your xml file create an EditText and set its following attribute

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

and when you click the button do the following programatically

```
edittext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

to show use and for hide use hide

```
edittext.setvisibility(View.VISIBLE);
edittext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: oh sorry it is not working for me so is there another way , but anyway thanks a lot